Getting "Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed." on production but not on local
I have this EF Core query:
public async Task<List<RuleEvent>> GetEnabledRuleEventsAsync(string eventName)
{
    return await _context.RuleEvents
                .Include(c => c.Rule)
                .Include(c => c.Event)
                .Where(c => c.Enabled && c.Rule.Enabled && c.Event.Name.ToLower().Trim() == eventName.ToLower().Trim())
                .ToListAsync();
}

On local system when debugged through Visual Studio it is working fine. But when deployed on production it is showing following error:

An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
context type '"ABCRepository.Entities.ABCContext"'."
""System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call
CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.

Following is how ABCContext is configured:
services.AddDbContext<ABCContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);


Hi Aishwarya Shiva， try to use ServiceLifetime.Scoped instead of ServiceLifetime.Transient when you AddDbContext.

Do you execute this method from background service?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv OP registered context as transient, so they won't be disposed of on HTTP request end.

@MichałTurczyn, it is not about disposing. OP may create singletone service, inject DbContext once (no difference which lifetime) and use this serice in concurrent environment.

Your implementation look ok. I think the problem lies in the way you call GetEnabledRuleEventsAsync - I think the exception might be caused by not awaiting this operation.
If you do not await the operation, your context willbe in use trying to execute the query, while the repository (class with GetEnabledRuleEventsAsync method) might go out of scope and get garbage collected together with context (calling its Dispose method).
That's how your connection could get closed during execution of the method.
